# Code Contract Runtime error message

Tags: c#, .net, code-contracts

How can I solve this problem by using Code contracts:

```
private string SomeMethod(string code)
{   
    var msg = "Invalid blabal " + code;
    Contract.Ensures(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), msg);
}
```

Error:

> User message to contract call can only be string literal, or a static
>   field, or static property that is at least internally visible.

**EDIT**:
I saw this information as you use contracts with similar use case

Answer (score 2):

All of the contract methods have overloads that take a string in addition to the boolean condition:

The user-supplied string will be displayed whenever the contract is violated at runtime.

**It must be a compile-time constant**.

So It must be:

```
Contract.Ensures(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "YOUR MASSAGE");
```

Answer (score 2):

[The documentation say that: (page 13)](http://research.microsoft.com/en-us/projects/contracts/userdoc.pdf)

> **2.10 Overloads on Contract Methods**
>
> All of the contract methods have overloads that take a string in
>   addition to the boolean condition:
>
> `Contract.Requires(x != null, "If x is null, then the missiles are red!");`
>
> The user-supplied string will be displayed whenever the contract is
>   violated at runtime. **Currently, it must be a compile-time constant**.

Your variable `msg` is obviously not a compile-time constant.
So instead, this will work:

```
Contract.Ensures(!string.IsNullOrEmpty(Contract.Result<string>()), "Invalid code");
```